# How to parse correctly a Date in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having the following error. I have a String = "2020-07-07" and I want it as Date so I can save it in my DB. So I did this:

```kotlin
val date = "2020-07-07"

val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US) 

formatter.parse(date)
```

---

But I am getting this:

```
Tue Jul 07 00:00:00 GMT-03:00 2020
```

What I am doing wrong? Please Help!

I have tried with formatter.format, but that returns a String and I want it to be a Date

The type of the variable after parsing MUST be Date, not LocalDate.

Comment: It sounds like you have a misunderstanding of what a `Date` is. You say "I dont want to get something like Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 CEST 2020", which doesn't really make sense. What you're seeing is the result of `Date.toString()`, which does not mean you do not have a `Date`.

Comment: @BenP.     What I meant was that I just want to convert the String to a Date, without changing the content

Comment: Which is exactly what you have done

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , LocalDate.parse( "2020-07-07" ) )
```

## `Date` class — not for dates

One of many flaws in the `java.util.Date` class is its name. It does *not* represent a date. That class represents a moment, a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC.

Adding to the confusion is that its `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone.

## Never use `Date`

Both the `java.util.Date` class and `java.sql.Date` class are terrible, flawed in design, written by people who did not understand date-time handling. Avoid them, along with `SimpleDateFormat` etc. Sun, Oracle, and the [JCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) community gave up on those classes years ago, and so should you.

## *java.time*

Those legacy classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use those formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2020-07-07" ) ;
```

## Database

You can exchange *java.time* object with your database as of JDBC 4.2 and later. Be sure your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is up-to-date.

You should be writing a `LocalDate` object to a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `DATE`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Answer (score 1):

Object of class Date can be printed in many formats.

```kotlin
val date: String = "2020-07-07"
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US) 
val dateDate: Date = formatter.parse(date) // You got Date object of 2020 jul 7

println(formatter.format(dateDate)) //it prints "2020-07-07"
println(dateDate)                   // without formatter it print default format 
                                    // "Tue Jul 07 00:00:00 GMT-03:00 2020"
```

Comment: These flawed classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already have the right code.
But the problem seems to be that you should use the correct string.
You present `2020-08-06` but then change it to `2020-07-07`.

The complete code is

```
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.ParseException
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

@Throws(ParseException::class)
fun main() {
    val rawDate: String = "2020-08-06"
    val format: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US)
    val date: Date = format.parse(rawDate)
    println(date)
}
```

I get `Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 CEST 2020` with `CEST` because I'm located in central Europe.

Also, this post [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) covers a lot of what you seek.

Comment: But the problem is that I dont want to get something like Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 CEST 2020. I just want the same content as the String (2020-07-07) but as Date. You know what I mean?

Comment: To be sure: You have a variable of type `String` and you want a variable of type `Date`, right?
If that's the case, the `date` variable has the type `Date` that you want.
However, when you print it, it will also print the time as 00:00:00 but that doesn't invalidate your `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

```
val dateString = "2020-07-05"
dateString.format(DateTime())
//Log.d("DateTest", dateString.format(DateTime()))
```

Try this. It should work. This converts a string to a DateTime() format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Locale.Default?

Answer (score 0):

you use Android so your DB is most likely SQLite (also when you use Room). That means that you cannot store data as Date, see here
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/

> SQLite does not support built-in date and/or time storage class. Instead, it leverages some built-in date and time functions to use other storage classes such as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER for storing the date and time values.

So basically you can store it e.g. as `Int` and then when you retrieve it you can convert it to `Date`

Answer (score 0):

```
val date = "2020-07-07"

val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") // change in this line 

formatter.parse(date)
```

This will work surely